# $.get in Jquery problem

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do an ajax (restful service) call using $.get.
It works perfectly in IE but gives '401 unauthorized' in case of firefox.

At first I thought it was 'NTLM authentication' issue and tried adding the domain( of restful service - eg: http://mydomain.com in about:config -> network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris  ) but no success.

I'm sure it's not the ntlm issue, as entering the same url (restful service) in the firefox browser is giving me the data, but gives 401 unauthorized through $.get.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here.

Thanks

#### Update:

I just figure out, it was due to 'cross domain' issue as sAc mentioned. I've one more doubt w.r.t JSONP, the service which I'm using doesn't support additional parameters in the url. but if i've to use JSONP callback, i've to add "callback=?" to the url. Is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: Are you fetching data from another domain?

Comment: if my server is on abc.xyz.domain.com, i'm trying to access data from efg.xyz.domain.com. I also tried this off the server, but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> if my server is on abc.xyz.domain.com,
>   i'm trying to access data from
>   efg.xyz.domain.com. I also tried this
>   off the server, but same error

The `abc.xyz.domain.com` and `efg.xyz.domain.com` are different domains:

Take a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> In computing, the same origin policy
>   is an important security concept for a
>   number of browser-side programming
>   languages, such as JavaScript. The
>   policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site
>   to access each other's methods and
>   properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to
>   most methods and properties across
>   pages on different sites.

You may want to have a look at [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) to get around it.

Comment: Thanks sAc, I'll go through JSONP and see if using that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this, it works for me (cross-domain too):

jQuery.ajax( { 
    async: true, // Cross-Domain requests doen't support synchronous operation. 
    crossDomain: true, dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: onSuccess, 
    error: onError, // This handler should not called for cross-domain script.
    url: "https://my.other.domain/test/login.py?callback=?" } );

Regards, 
Michel.